# heightForRowAtIndexPath not displaying multiline

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

heightForRowAtIndexPath is never displaying multiline when the text is longer than usual.

Here is my code:

```
#define FONT_SIZE 14.0f
#define CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH 320.0f
#define CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN 10.0f

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGFloat     result = 44.0f;
    CGFloat     width = 0;
    CGFloat     tableViewWidth;
    CGRect      bounds = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation))
        tableViewWidth = bounds.size.width;
    else
        tableViewWidth = bounds.size.height;

    width = tableViewWidth - 110;       // fudge factor, 115 isn't quite right

    NSUInteger index = [indexPath row];
    id doc = [[self displayedObjects] objectAtIndex:index];

    NSString *title = [doc title];  

    if (title)
    {
        // The notes can be of any height
        // This needs to work for both portrait and landscape orientations.
        // Calls to the table view to get the current cell and the rect for the 
        // current row are recursive and call back this method.
        CGSize      textSize = { width, 20000.0f };     // width and height of text area
        CGSize      size = [title sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f] constrainedToSize:textSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

        size.height += 29.0f;               // top and bottom margin
        result = MAX(size.height, 44.0f);   // at least one row
    }

    return result;
}
```

Any help will be really appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make label show multiline text you must set its numberOfLines property to a maximum allowed number of lines (or to 0 for arbitrary lines number). So in cellForRowAtIndexPath: method when setup your cell add:

```
...
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you don't use a custom UITableViewCell. So you're probably setting the title somewhere with something similar to the following code :

```
cell.textLabel.text = @"long long long text";
```

To get your text on multiple lines you have to configure the default title UILabel to display its text on multiple lines. Like this :

```
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 3;
```

You can compute the number of line the same way you compute the height of the cell. In fact I think you have to compute both to do what you want (height adapted to the content).

```
CGSize      size = [title sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f] constrainedToSize:textSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

What matters in `textSize` is to set the row width for the width attribute and an height value  which is "large" enough to "host" the text.

Once you have your `size` initialized you can divide the height by the height of the UILabel line.

Comment: Hi Florian, the problem is that I do not know how many lines should the text use (Is variable), so setting numberOfLines=3 I guess it will not work for every cell.